# Matplotlib and DataFrame errors ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous || invalid value encountered in det

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, spyder

I am trying to clean up my data which consists of 5 excel files (calibration solutions 1-5) with multiple columns each (sensor1, sensor2, sensor3) to DataFrames. The problem (due to the nature of the experimental setup) is that in every calibration point file, the sensors are measuring a different calibration solution. So I would have a dataframe **calibration1:**

| sensor1 solution1 | sensor2 solution2 | sensor3 solution3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 180 | 12 | 300 |
| 182 etc. | 14 etc. | 302 etc. |

and **calibration2:** and so on

| sensor1 solution2 | sensor2 solution3 | sensor3 solution1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 304 | 179 |
| 13 etc. | 302 etc. | 178 etc. |

I combined the according columns in all calibration dataframes, so that I have a ***dataframe for each solution*** (pH), for example ***pH1***

| sensor1 solution1 | sensor2 solution1 | sensor3 solution1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 180 | 181 | 179 |
| 182 | 180 | 178 |

See example **calibration dataframe** from my data called **calibration1**

```
datetime    TempC   Sensor1 Sensor2 Sensor3
2023-03-22 16:16:37 24.992  -177.3  309.0   175.7
2023-03-22 16:16:40 24.992  -177.3  309.0   175.7
2023-03-22 16:16:43 24.992  -177.3  309.0   175.8
2023-03-22 16:16:46 24.992  -177.3  309.0   175.7
2023-03-22 16:16:49 24.993  -177.3  309.0   175.7
2023-03-22 16:16:52     -177.4  309.0   175.7
2023-03-22 16:16:55 24.993  -177.4  309.0   175.7
2023-03-22 16:16:58 24.993  -177.4  309.0   175.7
2023-03-22 16:17:01 24.993  -177.4  309.0   175.7
2023-03-22 16:17:04     -177.4  309.0   175.7
2023-03-22 16:17:07 24.993  -177.4  309.0   175.7
```

and example ***solution dataframe***: called ***pH9***

```
    Sensor1 Sensor2 Sensor3
0   311.3   309.2   313.0
1   311.4   309.2   313.0
2   311.3   309.2   313.0
3   311.3   309.2   313.0
4   311.3   309.2   313.0
5   311.4   309.1   313.0
6   311.3   309.2   313.0
7   311.3   309.2   313.0
8   311.3   309.1   313.0
9   311.3   309.1   312.9
10  311.3   309.1   313.0
11  311.3   309.2   313.0
12  311.3   309.1   313.0
13  311.3   309.1   313.0
```

I don't know what happened during my analysis, but now I started getting error messages when calculating a mean or plotting a boxplot or violinplot. strangely enough, I can access the data and it seems fine:

```
In [31]: pH9.Sensor1
Out[33]: 
0     -133.0
1     -133.0
2     -133.0
3     -133.0
4     -133.0
 
297      NaN
298      NaN
299      NaN
300      NaN
301      NaN
Name: Sensor1, Length: 302, dtype: float64
```

but when I calculate the mean it works but I get this huge error:

```
pH9.Sensor1.mean()
Out[34]: -133.0027777777778

[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 409, in dispatch_shell
    await result
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 798, in inspect_request
    reply_content = self.do_inspect(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 555, in do_inspect
    bundle = self.shell.object_inspect_mime(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1838, in object_inspect_mime
    return self.inspector._get_info(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py", line 738, in _get_info
    info_dict = self.info(obj, oname=oname, info=info, detail_level=detail_level)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py", line 838, in info
    if info and info.parent and hasattr(info.parent, HOOK_NAME):
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1527, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Also I should be able to draw a boxplot? I have a dataframe with columns and float data, why is it not possible?

I can plot: and get a boxplot

```
pH9.mean().plot(kind='bar')
```

[barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbwxf.png)

but with plt.violinplot() I get a violinplot that is only 1 violin and this strange ***invalid value encountered in det*** warning.

```
In [42]: plt.violinplot(dataset=pH9)
C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py:2139: RuntimeWarning:

invalid value encountered in det

Out[42]: 
{'bodies': [<matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection at 0x24a9526e490>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection at 0x24a955b0090>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection at 0x24a955bc310>],
 'cmaxes': <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x24a95436890>,
 'cmins': <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x24a955be9d0>,
 'cbars': <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection at 0x24a955bd490>}
```

[violinplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPpya.png)

I tried to see, if there is something wrong with my dataframe columns, which shows me the expected output

BUT I AGAIN get this huge error

```
In [43]: pH9.keys()
Out[43]: Index(['Sensor1', 'Sensor2', 'Sensor3'], dtype='object')
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 409, in dispatch_shell
    await result
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 798, in inspect_request
    reply_content = self.do_inspect(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 555, in do_inspect
    bundle = self.shell.object_inspect_mime(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1838, in object_inspect_mime
    return self.inspector._get_info(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py", line 738, in _get_info
    info_dict = self.info(obj, oname=oname, info=info, detail_level=detail_level)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py", line 838, in info
    if info and info.parent and hasattr(info.parent, HOOK_NAME):
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1527, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I feel like this did not happen when I started.. I now tried to update conda, numpy, restart spyder, restart computer. Didn't help :(

The only problem I can think of, is that something went wrong when I tried to jointhe data columns as not all of them have equal number of rows (and again the error message):

```
pH1 = sensor1.reset_index(drop=True).join(sensor2.reset_index(drop=True), how='outer').join(sensor3.reset_index(drop=True), how='outer')
```

```
In[44]: pH1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 302 entries, 0 to 301
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------   --------------  -----  
 0   Sensor1  277 non-null    float64
 1   Sensor2  182 non-null    float64
 2   Sensor3  302 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(3)
memory usage: 9.4 KB

[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 409, in dispatch_shell
    await result
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 798, in inspect_request
    reply_content = self.do_inspect(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 555, in do_inspect
    bundle = self.shell.object_inspect_mime(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1838, in object_inspect_mime
    return self.inspector._get_info(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py", line 738, in _get_info
    info_dict = self.info(obj, oname=oname, info=info, detail_level=detail_level)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py", line 838, in info
    if info and info.parent and hasattr(info.parent, HOOK_NAME):
  File "C:\Users\CMerz\Anaconda3\envs\Working\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1527, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I suggest that you try to narrow down the problem so you either find the problem yourself or have some code to share. For example you can create a dummy data that you perform your analysis on, try to replicate the error and share this code with us. for example: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((10, 2)), colums=["col1", "col2"])` et cetera. Maybe you must add a `np.nan` value for the error to show up (which I dont think since the errors seems unrealted to nan values).

Comment: The tracebacks indicate that the problem is in the Spyder/ipython interface, possibly because it's trying to format some sort of warning or other information.  The "underlying" calculations seem to be working.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem as you have, and it is truly quite annoying. For me installing earlier versions of Spyder solved the problem (I installed Spyder 5.4.0). You can use anaconda to install earlier versions of Spyder. I don't think Spyder's official website offers downloads of previous versions.

I don't know what exactly had happened since I'm new to Python/Spyder and I've been messing around with my MacBook quite a lot recently, and I don't know it's my problem or Spyder's. However, this tentatively solved my problem and now my Spyder works well.